# Modify behavior of named route in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

In my rails blog I'm writing I want the "show" route for posts to always have the form of:

> /year/month/day/title

Currently I can accomplish this using a generic match:

```
match "/:year/:month/:day/:url_title", :to => "posts#show", :constraints => {:year => /(19|20)\d\d/, :month => /[01]?\d/, :day => /[0-3]?\d/}
```

Where my model is responsible for converting the title into a hyphen delimited string.

However, I need a way to integrate this behavior into the resource routing so that my post_path methods will continue to work - preferably by just passing in a post object.

I'm wondering if there's some way I can use the :as option to set the route, or do it with a block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered the question yourself just use `:as => :post` then `post_path(@post)` will work!

Comment: Oh! Well, I'm actually trying that now, but getting an error that no route matches those options, even though it's correctly applying the correct fields. I wonder if I have an error in my regex somewhere.

Comment: Yeah. The post_path(@post) also doesn't work if I just remove the constraints entirely, which seems odd.

Comment: could you post your match route with the `:as`?

Comment: match '/:year/:month/:day/:url_title' => "posts#show", :constraints => {:year => /(19|20)\d\d/, :month => /[01]?\d/, :day => /[0-3]?\d/, :url_title => /.*/}, :as => 'post'

Comment: Errr, sorry, that -doesn't- work with the "as", actually. Sorry about that, must have clicked refresh after removing it the first time.

Comment: It looks like, with the "as" there, it tries to put the entire Post object in the :year field

Comment: oops, my mistake its `:as => :post` not `:as => 'post'`

Comment: Seems to do the same thing either way

Comment: try putting the `:as` for before the `:constraints`, I know it shouldn't have anything to do with it. but you never know whats going to work

Comment: That didn't work, but if I remove the constraints I can go to the url directly with the :as there. the post_path still breaks though

Comment: Well, I've gotten it to where the post_path works on the show screen (not on the index view that lists posts), but for some reason the year is coming out as 2 instead of 2011. Any ideas on that?

Comment: it will be something to do with the year regular expression

Comment: I've already removed that, actually. It looks like it's pulling the id instead of the year for the :year field.

Comment: Going to go ahead and accept this answer, since I'm pretty sure this is -how- you do it, and post another question as to why mine doesn't work.